# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl Flickers On Dismissal

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, flicker

I have a view controller with the following method:

```
- (IBAction)pickLocation:(id)sender{
    SearchLocationPickerViewController *modalView = [[[SearchLocationPickerViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [modalView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    modalView.searchVC = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
}
```

This transitions perfectly fine, and displays the modal view controller as expected. However, when I dismiss the modal view using the following (executed from the modal view controller):

```
- (IBAction)closeLocationPick:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The modal view transitions out as expected, but right at the end of the transition, the display will really quickly flicker *SOMETIMES*. It displays the modal view that was just displaying for a fraction of a second. This only happens maybe every three out of ten times of showing / hiding the modal view.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: i tried your code & could not reproduce.can you elaborate what actually happens

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your post correctly, one problem may be that you are dismissing the modal view from within itself.  While this does work, it is not the way in which Apple prefers.  I am making the inference that this may muck with the animation of the view as it is dismissed.

Your IBAction should be calling a delegate method in the modal view controllers parent, the one that created and presented the modal view controller originally.  You define the delegate protocol in your modal view controller and adopt it in the view controller that makes the presentModalViewController: call.

[Here are the relevant Apple docs on dismissing a model view.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14)

Comment: You can still dismiss correctly from the modal in iOS 5+ using [[self presentingViewController] dismissModal...]